# Segmentation Fault using Tinyxml

Tags: c++, tinyxml

I'm trying to read an Xml file recursively using Tinyxml, but when I try to acces the data I get a "Segmentation Fault". here is the code :

```
int id=0, categoria=0;
const char* nombre;
do{  
    ingrediente = ingrediente->NextSiblingElement("Ingrediente");   
    contador++;  
    if(ingrediente->Attribute("id")!=NULL)
        id = atoi( ingrediente->Attribute("id") );  
    if(ingrediente->Attribute("categoria")!=NULL)
        categoria = atoi ( ingrediente->Attribute("categoria") );  
    if(ingrediente!=NULL)
        nombre = ( ( ingrediente->FirstChild() )->ToText() )->Value();  
}while(ingrediente);
```

For some reason, the three "if" lines throws me the Segmentation Fault but I've not idea about where is the problem.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: It looks like you check if ingrediente!=NULL on the third if but not on the first two.  If ingrediente really was null then those first two if's would throw a segmentation fault.  You should open this up with a debugger to find out exactly what is NULL.

Comment: You'd get a precise answer if you'd post a complete code, and don't forget to use the "code" tag so it gets formatted properly. I suggest you edit.

Comment: And you'll do even better if you'll post a "mini-version" of the XML you're parsing.

Answer (score 1):

Your're updating `ingrediente` at the start of each iteration, and then dereferencing it before you check that it's not null. This will give a segmentation fault if it is null. The loop should probably be structured along the lines of

```
for (ingrediente = first_ingrediente; 
     ingrediente; 
     ingrediente = ingrediente->NextSiblingElement("Ingrediente"))
    contador++;  
    if(ingrediente->Attribute("id"))
        id = atoi( ingrediente->Attribute("id") );  
    if(ingrediente->Attribute("categoria"))
        categoria = atoi ( ingrediente->Attribute("categoria") );  
    nombre = ingrediente->FirstChild()->ToText()->Value();  
}
```

Sorry for mixing some English into the variable names; I don't speak Spanish.

Or, if `NextSiblingElement` gives you the first element when you start iterating, the `for` can be replaced with `while`:

```
while ((ingrediente = ingrediente->NextSiblingElement("Ingrediente")))
```

The important point is to check for null after getting the pointer, and before dereferencing it.